# Reliable SOAP Messaging - Use JMS queue or own implementation?

Tags: java, soap, jms, osgi, activemq-classic

I'm confronted with a system (Java, OSGI-based, Equinox, Blueprint) that needs to send asynchronous notifications via SOAP messages to a remote system. The system must ensure that the notifications reach the remote system (i.e. it reponses with a confirmation message, WS-ReliableMessaging is not available).

Now I see two Options:

1. Use the EventAdmin mechanism of OSGI to trigger the notifications, implement my own handler which persists the notification in a queue. A quartz job would poll the queue and try to send the Soap message. The message would only be removed from the queue if the remote system reponses successfully.
2. Use a messaging middleware like ActiveMQ (e.g. as part of Apache Servicemix) to make use of JMS and make the whole task a lot easier.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Take JMS, if you go for 1 you'll end up implementing some of the stuff that is already provided by a JMS system. OSGi events are nice, but after a shutdown of the container they are gone. So this will be at least one of the drawbacks that you'll have to re-implement that a JMS messaging system like ActiveMQ already provides.

Comment: so how can I use JMS to consume a message from the queue and only remove it if the SOAP Messaging with the remote system was successful?